# Header Links not working Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently using Michael Hartl's tutorial to create a blog site. I am having some trouble with my header links as they are not appearing on any of my pages.

Including my routes file, header.html.erb file. Please let me know if there is anything else I can include to help.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  get 'blog_pages/home'

  get 'about' => 'blog_pages#about'

  get 'goodstuff' => 'blog_pages#goodstuff'

  get 'serenity' => 'blog_pages#serenity'

  get 'contact' => 'blog_pages#contact'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'application#Blog'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your application.html.erb file please?

Comment: @ruby_newbie - Added!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did these steps as below:

your name file `header.html.erb` have `underscore` as `_header.html.erb`

And in your `application.html.erb` you must set as:

`<%= render partial: "header" %>` (`_header.html.erb` and `application.html.erb` must live same directory)

Comment: Hi Khan Pham,
I have confirmed that the filenames do have the underscores. In regards to adding the header partial, where exactly would I put that in my application.html.erb file?

Comment: It depends on where you want the header.  Likely right under this line: "<div class="container">"

Comment: Thanks for the input. i will play with this immediately after work and let ya know!

Thanks again,

Comment: No problem.  If Khanh's solution solves your problem please be sure to mark it as correct.

Comment: So as soon as I add that line to my application.html.erb file under the line as you stated, i get the following "template missing" error:

Missing partial blog_pages/_header, application/_header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/guud_blog/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

Any thoughts?